# How do I access data from another domain in clean archecture

Tags: clean-architecture

My app has 2 features (HomePage, FavoritePage)

```
- HomePage
  - domain
  - data
  - presentation
- FavoritePage
  - domain
  - data
  - presentation
```

Shortcuts to FavoritePage can be placed on the HomePage, and there is a button on FavoritePage that displays different ICONS depending on whether they are currently placed

the question is: In a clean architecture, different domains are not allowed to communicate with each other, so how do I access and set shortcuts on the HomePage?

Thanks